# Manually use numbering sequence

Tags: acumatica

I have created a numbering sequence that I would like to use for a portion of an identifier.  Is there a special method to use to retrieve the next number or is it as simple as retrieving the sequence and manually updating the record?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the AutoNumberAttribute.
There is a bunch of static methods that could be interesting to you, but to generate the next number you would use :

```
var numberingValue = AutoNumberAttribute.GetNextNumber(cache, row, numberingID, date);
```

Comment: I am not using the autonumber attribute.  This is not for the next id number for a record name.  I need to create a 17 digit number composed of 3 pieces:  <7 digit gs1 prefix for account><9 digit sequential unique number><mod 10 check digit>.  I wanted to use the numbering sequence instead of creating another field somewhere.

Comment: You pass whatever numbering sequence ID you want to the AutoNumberAttribute.GetNextNumber method, it will generate the next number for that sequence.

Comment: @JerryWelliver, There's a similar logic on Payment Method's cash account "Last Check Number". The purpose is to get the next check number and be able to change the last check number used if error happened.